# Practical Nonsense

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, crosswords

Here's an enigmatic puzzle I created. **The answer will be one word.**

*I don't understand these symbols, but hey, at least they work!*
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each of the symbols below the crossword grid

> is a Unicode symbol in the [miscellaneous technical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscellaneous_Technical) block. Taking the names of these symbols gives:
>
>  **DEL STILE**
>  **DELTA UNDERBAR**
>  **EPSILON UNDERBAR**
>  **QUAD JOT**
>  **QUAD LESS THAN**
>  **SLASH BAR**
>  **SQUISH QUAD**
>  **UP SHOE JOT**
>  **UPWARDS VANE**

These are entered in the grid as so:

> [image: practical_nonsense_grid]

Finally, taking the letters in the yellow squares gives us the final answer of

> **SPARTAN**